# Save a numpy array consisting of numpy arrays different shapes to a .txt file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, saving-data

I am a beginner in Python. Here's what I am trying to do :

```python
import numpy as np 
r10 = np.array([[i for i in range(0,10)],[i*10 for i in range(0,10)]]).T
r6 = np.array([[i for i in range(0,6)],[i*10 for i in range(0,6)]]).T
r_comb = np.array([[r10],[r6]]).T
np.savetxt('out.txt',r_comb)
```

Using np.savetxt gives me the following error since it only supports 1-D array  :

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1433                 try:
-> 1434                     v = format % tuple(row) + newline
   1435                 except TypeError:

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-c3147f076055> in <module>
----> 1 np.savetxt('out.txt',r_comb)

<__array_function__ internals> in savetxt(*args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1434                     v = format % tuple(row) + newline
   1435                 except TypeError:
-> 1436                     raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
   1437                                     "format specifier ('%s')"
   1438                                     % (str(X.dtype), format))

TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e')
```

Is there any other way of saving the contents of the variable r_comb to a .txt file so that I can use it for other plotting programs?
Basically,I want the text file to look like this :

```python
0 0.0 0 0.0
1 0.1 1 0.1
2 0.2 2 0.2
3 0.3 3 0.3
4 0.4 4 0.4
5 0.5 5 0.5
6 0.6
7 0.7
8 0.8
9 0.9
```

Image showing how the contents of the text file should look

[image]

Comment: You can't do that (with just one call to `savetxt`).  And the result will be harder to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky but works

```
import numpy as np 
r10 = np.array([[i for i in range(0,10)],[i*10 for i in range(0,10)]]).T
r6 = np.array([[i for i in range(0,6)],[i*10 for i in range(0,6)]]).T

# np array with nans
data = np.empty((np.max([r10.shape[0], r6.shape[0]]),4))
data[:] = np.NaN
for i in range(2):
  data[0:len(r10[:,i]), i] = r10[:, i]

for i in range(2):
  data[0:len(r6[:,i]), i+2] = r6[:, i]

# replace nans and save
data = data.astype(str)
data[data=='nan'] = ''
np.savetxt("out.txt", data, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

Contents of `out.txt`

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 10.0 1.0 10.0
2.0 20.0 2.0 20.0
3.0 30.0 3.0 30.0
4.0 40.0 4.0 40.0
5.0 50.0 5.0 50.0
6.0 60.0  
7.0 70.0  
8.0 80.0  
9.0 90.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `r_comb` is an array of arrays:

```
In [313]: r_comb                                                                        
Out[313]: 
array([[array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 4, 40],
       [ 5, 50],
       [ 6, 60],
       [ 7, 70],
       [ 8, 80],
       [ 9, 90]]),
        array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 4, 40],
       [ 5, 50]])]], dtype=object)
In [314]: _.shape                                                                       
Out[314]: (1, 2)
```

`savetxt` is designed to save a nice numeric 2d array.  The default `fmt` is '%.18e' (**read the docs**).  Obviously that can't format an array.

I could 'flatten' that into one 2d array with:

```
In [320]: np.vstack(r_comb[0,:])                                                        
Out[320]: 
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 4, 40],
       ....
       [ 4, 40],
       [ 5, 50]])
```

and write that to a file with (note the change in `fmt`):

```
In [321]: np.savetxt('test.csv', np.vstack(r_comb[0,:]), fmt='%5d')                     
In [322]: cat test.csv                                                                  
    0     0
    1    10
    2    20
    3    30
    4    40
    ...
    4    40
    5    50
```

The layout you propose does not fit the example array.  And even if you managed to write it, how do you propose to read it?  The `numpy` readers expect a consistent number of columns in each row.

```
0 0.0 0 0.0
1 0.1 1 0.1
2 0.2 2 0.2
3 0.3 3 0.3
4 0.4 4 0.4
5 0.5 5 0.5
6 0.6
7 0.7
8 0.8
9 0.9
```

You could call `savetxt` twice on the same file (with `append` mode if needed), and save the two arrays one after the other.  And with some work you could also load it with two calls to `genfromtxt`.  But that's a lot of work for a Python beginner!

Comment: I don't really require reading from the text file again using NumPy. I just use the text file for plotting my data using programs like XmGrace. This problem is a part of a bigger project I am working on. Basically, I get spectroscopic  data in the form of a binary file, which I read into numpy arrays and use it for plotting and some other data analysis using python. I just need the text files to plot later using things other than Python.

Comment: Write one array.  Then append the second.